# Create a WCF service from a xml SOAP call

Tags: webservice, soap, wcf

Tengo que crear una api webservice que se adapte exactamente igual a la llamada que realiza una aplicación.
No soy experto en WCF y por lo que veo, utiliza mutiples namespace en el ServiceContract y no tiene namespace en el dataContract. 
Si pueden ayudarme con la definición de los namespace, el resto ya es crear las clases.

Gracias

Ejemplo de la llamada

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>
<soap:Body>
<ns2:CreateDATA xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/APP.WSInterface" xmlns:ns2="http://tempuri.org/">
<ns2:woCreationDATA>
    <Client>
        <ContactAddress>XXXXXXX</ContactAddress>
        <CustomerComments xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
    </ClientData>
</ns2:woCreationDATA>
</ns2:CreateDATA>
</soap:Body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Un proyecto WCF puede tener multiples endpoints y cada Endpoint aparte de tener distintas tipo de conexiones como http, https, tcp, pipe, etc. tambien puede apuntar a contratos diferentes de tu proyecto por si quieres parcializar tus API. Si lo consumes desde windows o .Net no es necesario cambiar los namespace si lo consumes desde java por ejemplo por un tema de compatibilidad puedes Decorar tu interface con tu propio namespace.

```
[ServiceContract (Namespace ="MiNameSpace")]
```

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/servicemodel-attributes-and-servicedescription-reference